# How to get-content with username & password

Tags: powershell

How do I get-content from a text file from multiple remote PCs with username & password?

I want data from **WSUS.txt** from client computer and I have the IP address of the client computer on **S.txt**.  I wrote the Powershell script below, but it does not work:

```
$computers = Get-Content -Path .\S.txt

$Credential= Get-Credential -Credential Whatusername?

foreach ($svr in $Computers) {    
     Get-Content \\$svr\Upgrade\CUSTOMER-INV\WSUS.TXT -Credential $Credential >> d:\WSUS.log    
}
```

Comment: What error message, if any, do you get? If you don't get an error message, what actually happens?

Comment: Is \\ServerX\Upgrade\CUSTOMER-INV\WSUS.TXT a valid path, meaning "\\ServerX\Upgrade" is a valid share?

Answer (score 0):

Its not super pretty but you can use **net use \server\ipc$** to authenticate if you dont want to use the current security context.

This only works if you have not already authenticated with the server (ie tried to access it with \\server\something)

so something like this:

```
foreach ($svr in $Computers) {   
     net use \\$server\ipc$ /user:$server\$user $password 
     Get-Content \\$svr\Upgrade\CUSTOMER-INV\WSUS.TXT -Credential $Credential >> d:\WSUS.log    
}
```